# How do slaves in sectors get managed?

Tags: stellaris

Do sector governors enslave/emancipate pops, or is it always up to the player to manage slavery manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sector AI will not currently (1.1.0) enslave or emancipate pops. However, the player is able to enslave / emancipate any pop, even those pops within a sector. So to answer -- the sector does not do so, and it is up to the player to assess the needs etc. of their sectors.

What the Sector AI *will* do is make sure that any slaves it *does* have are working Food / Mineral tiles, rather than Energy or Research.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the player to manage slavery/emancipation. Playing a game where the vast majority of the planets that have been taken from other empires are enslaved and then added to a sector. They've been like that for over 100 years in game time and have not had their status changed

Answer (score 0):

I have run a game just yesterday where in a 16 planet full of slaves, the sector AI decided to build four research platforms. Stellaris is on latest patch, through Steam.

So I did some testing on three different slave planets:

a) killed all but three slaves on one planet, let the Sector AI develop the planet with a mineral focus with "Allow redevelopment" "Do not respect tiles". AI built four research stations

b) Build all slaves as mineral and power, split evenly (after food requirements). Let the Sector AI manage the planet with a mineral focus with "Allow redevelopment" "Do not respect tiles". AI built loads of power and 4 research stations.

c) Build all slaves as mineral and power, split evenly (after food requirements). Let the Sector AI manage the planet with a mineral focus with "Allow redevelopment" "Respect tiles". AI built research on research, power on power, mineral on mineral and the empty lots (four) it filled with two power, and two research.

lots of tiles wasted on research of 0.3 point per month! They could be making 10 minerals or 8 power each (at my current tech level)

The AI is just insane :P